# Install IntelliJ with Android-SDK

Tags: 18.04, intellij, android-sdk

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I have downloaded IntelliJ (Community version) from the website and installed it according to the instructions. I have installed android-sdk via `sudo apt-get install android-sdk`. Now I start IntelliJ, click on Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure. Then I click on "New" and choose "Android SDK". Next I navigate to /usr/lib/android-sdk. I choose that location and hit "OK". Next I see the error message "Cannot find any Android targets in this SDK". I do not know how to handle this error message. I have downloaded the android SDK from the official repository and point IntelliJ to that location, what's the problem here?

Comment: I'm still stuck on this ...